# Store named ranges values as variable

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to store a named range like that

```
    Dim sValue As String
sValue = ThisWorkbook.Names("MyRange").Value
```

I got the range address instead of the values in the named range. What I am trying to do exactly is the following
Suppose the named range is "MyRange" and it is for A1:C4 
In a cell, if we typed equal sign and typed "MyRange" and then pressed F9, we got the values as array like that

```
{"Head1","Head2","Head3";1,2,3;4,5,6;7,8,9}
```

How to store that in variable string?

Comment: `Dim sValue As Variant`

Comment: Thanks a lot. Using Variant is the same as the result is the address of the range not the values .. I need to store the same output that appears after pressing F9 in the worksheet formula and I have posted it above.

Comment: `sValue = ThisWorkbook.Names("MyRange").RefersToRange.Value`

Comment: that will give you back an array with named range values

Answer (score 3, accepted):

to have a `String` variable formatted as {"Head1","Head2","Head3";1,2,3;4,5,6;7,8,9}, you can do as follows

```
    Dim sValue As String, r As Range
    For Each r In ThisWorkbook.Names("MyRange").RefersToRange.Rows
        sValue = sValue & Join(Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(r.Value)), ",") & ";"
    Next
    sValue = "{" & Left(sValue, Len(sValue) - 1) & "}"
```

while to store a named range in an array is much simpler (and I'd say, easy to use):

```
Dim sValue As Variant
sValue = ThisWorkbook.Names("MyRange").RefersToRange.Value
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for great help. At the end of your code I tried such a line `a = Evaluate(sValue)` but I got Error 2015 for the value of a in the Locals Window. Why?

Comment: You are welcome. I'm not an `Evaluate()` expert, but I'd say it would "eat" formulas, not arrays

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for

```
sValue = ThisWorkbook.Names("MyRange"),name
```

to find all names on Activesheet:

```
Sub test_names()
    Dim wsName As String
    wsName = ActiveSheet.Name
    Dim nameRange As Variant
    For Each nameRange In ThisWorkbook.Names
        Set rngName = Range(nameRange)
        wsParentName = rngName.Parent.CodeName
If (wsParentName = wsName) Then
Debug.Print "Found range " & nameRange.Name
End If
    Next nameRange
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot but this is irrelevant to the issue.